# Asp .NET Read a file from a tar.gz archive

Tags: c#, asp.net, archive, tar

I have some files inside in one .tar.gz archive. These files are on a linux server.How can I read from a specific file inside this archive if I know it's name?
For reading direct from the txt file, I used the following code:

```
Uri urlFile = new Uri("ftp://" + ServerName + "/%2f" + FilePath + "/" + fileName);
WebClient req = new WebClient() { Credentials=new NetworkCredential("user","psw")};
string result = req.DownloadString(urlFile);
```

It's possible to read this file without copying the archive on the local machine, something like the code above?

Comment: I don't think think tar balls work like zip files, you'd have to download the file then unpack it to get the txt file from it I would think.

Comment: I tried and this solution. Using the following code, I download the archive(gz) from server to local, extract the tar file, but I can't know how to extract one specific file from this archive.

Comment: `WebClient wc = new WebClient() { Credentials = cred };
            wc.DownloadFile(path, gzFile.FullName);


            using (FileStream inFile = gzFile.OpenRead())
            {
                using (FileStream tarFileStream = File.Create(tarFile.FullName))
                {
                    using (GZipStream decompStreem = new GZipStream(inFile, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        decompStreem.CopyTo(tarFileStream);

                    }
                }

            }`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to extract a single file form an archive like ... i think you have to extract the whole archive to a folder then read the file you want

Comment: I manage successfully to extract all files from this archive and delete it after reading (using `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib` library), but I don't think that is a good solution. If two users try to read this files simultaneously, one user can delete files before that second will be able to read it.

Comment: You can always mark the file in use on the server until either the user releases it in some way or the session ends. This is version control type behaviour and not a simple scenario to answer without a series of smaller questions I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. Maybe this can help you guys.

```
// archivePath="ftp://myLinuxServer.com/%2f/move/files/archive/20170225.tar.gz";
    public static string ExtractFileFromArchive(string archivePath, string fileName)
    {
        string stringFromFile="File not found";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient() { Credentials = cred, Proxy= webProxy  };        //Create webClient with all necessary settings 

        using (Stream source = new GZipInputStream(wc.OpenRead(archivePath)))  //wc.OpenRead() create one stream with archive tar.gz from our server
        {
            using (TarInputStream tarStr =new TarInputStream(source))   //TarInputStream is a stream from ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tar library(need install SharpZipLib in nutgets)
            {
                TarEntry te;
                while ((te = tarStr.GetNextEntry())!=null)  // Go through all files from archive
                {
                    if (te.Name == fileName)
                    {
                        using (Stream fs = new MemoryStream())  //Create a empty stream that we will be fill with file contents.
                        {
                            tarStr.CopyEntryContents(fs);
                            fs.Position = 0;                    //Move stream position to 0, in order to read from beginning
                            stringFromFile = new StreamReader(fs).ReadToEnd(); //Convert stream to string
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return stringFromFile;
    }
```